# Execute code once in several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let's suppose, that I have code, where program should show user some sort of UI dialog, and depending on dialog result, execute on of two actions. If I have several threads, each running this code, I will get several dialogs, one for each thread.
Question is - what if I want one dialog instead of multiple (for example, called by first thread, executing this code)? And result of this one dialog should affect all subsequent threads instead of showing dialog for each of them. How can I do this?

Just to mention, I can modify only mentioned part of code, so modifying source of threads is forbidden.

Comment: Make a static instance.

Comment: @Kevin Kal, well, this is certainly possible, but how can I make all threads use result of same dialog?

Comment: Oh, that might be not a problem, i've got it.

Comment: All UI needs to be on the one thread. Both WinForms and WPF are single-threaded.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's another question. I'm dispatching call to UI thread, but several threads do this several times.

Comment: Why don't your wrap the dialog box code up in a `Task<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the dialog. Add some functions to it that handles everything.

To use the result on all the threads, just save the result somewhere in the instance, so you can acquire it everywhere. There are multiple ways on how to do things like this. You can add an EventHandler to the singleton and every thread created makes a link to that event. Execute it whenever you get a result. Or make another static variable like `Singleton.LastResult`

Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) about Singleton's in C#. Make sure you handle everything correctly though. When it closes, destruct the instance.

Comment: It may require `lock` statement, since even if i use something like `if(dialog == null)`, several threads may succeed before actual dialog will be instantiated. And again, one thread may destroy instance, even if it was not still used by another threads.

Comment: Ofcourse you would need make a lock. And for the second problem, that's why you should make something like:
`public static int DialogResult { get; private set; }`